# How to configure Intel Wireless N 7260 on Ubuntu Server 20.04.1

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, iwlwifi

I've just installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 on a Sony Vaio Pro laptop. I'm not sure how to configure the Wi-Fi chip. The chip is an Intel Dual Band Wireless N 7260. The same laptop previously had Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 and connected to Wi-Fi networks without any issue or setup.

Logs from dmesg about wifi:

```
$ dmesg | grep wifi
[     4.620026] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[     4.636027] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[     4.684208] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144
[     4.703401] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: 5c:51:4f:0c:97:02
[     4.912092] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
```

My netplan:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      access-points:
        "***":
          password: "***"
```

ping results:

```
$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

ip output:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:51:4f:0c:97:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I've tried various netplans, running `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply` afterwards and rebooting. I get the 2-minute startup task timeout for Wait for Network to be Configured, can't ping anything, and `sudo apt-get update` gives `Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'`.

Not sure where to go from here, other than back to Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. Any ideas? This is my first time trying to use Ubuntu Server.

Comment: You reinstalled the same OS? If so why?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu Server. Ubuntu Desktop was previously installed.

Comment: If there's a simple way to go from Desktop to Server without installing fresh, I'll absolutely try and accept that as a solution if it works!

Comment: I would say a fresh install is the only way to go each time you try to do this it will get worse and worse. Server and desktop are very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo! A great article by Yu Ping solved this for me: https://medium.com/@yping88/how-to-enable-wi-fi-on-ubuntu-server-20-04-without-a-wired-ethernet-connection-42e0b71ca198

I'll describe what I did here, for others:

Ubuntu Server needed the wpasupplicant package, which isn't included in the ISO.

1. On a separate machine running Ubuntu Desktop, which comes with wpasupplicant, I repackaged it and its dependencies:

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt install -y dpkg-repack
    sudo dpkg-repack wpasupplicant libnl-route-3-200 libpcsclite1
   ```
2. I did this from my home folder, so that's where `dpkg-repack` produced the three .deb packages. Then I drag & dropped the .debs into a USB drive.
3. I plugged the USB drive into my machine running Ubuntu Server, mounted it, and installed the packages:

   ```
    sudo mkdir /media/usb
    sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
    cd /media/usb
    sudo dpkg -i libnl-route-3-200_3.4.0-1_amd64.deb \
      libpcsclite1_1.8.26-3_amd64.deb \
      wpasupplicant_2.9-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb
   ```
4. The final netplan I landed on is:

   ```
    network:
      ethernets: {}
      wifis:
        wlp1s0:
          dhcp4: true
          optional: true
          access-points:
            "***":
              password: "***"
      version: 2
      renderer: networkd
   ```
5. After configuring my netplan (`/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`), I applied it and rebooted:

   ```
    sudo netplan apply
    sudo reboot now
   ```

My Intel Wireless N 7260 now connects to my router, and I'm successfully pinging and running `apt-get update` as I type this.